# Representing Recursion and Primitive Recursion diagrammatically

Tags: functions, logic, computability, recursion

I'm interested in how Recursion, and Primitive Recursion, could be represented ***diagrammatically***. It occurred to me that this would be a good way of seeing the difference. Also, I'm interested in how Recursive functions in their various different forms could be represented this way.

If anyone knows of a method of drawing diagrams to visualise the behaviour of recursion and recursive functions, I'd love to learn more about it on this thread!

Comment: I am not sure I totally understand your question. For example, people have used all sorts of methods including UML. Is something like this [**Recursion Diagrams: ideas for a Geometry of Formal Methods**](http://www.bcs.org/upload/pdf/ewic_fa98_paper4.pdf) the sort of thing you had in mind? Regards

Comment: Thanks for your comment- it might well be the sort of thing I had in mind! Looks really interesting anyway. I have edited the second paragraph in my question, so that it is hopefully a little clearer what I mean. In general, I'm interested in any form of visual representation of recursion, and recursive functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what a *diagrammatic* representation would come to here. But here's a vivid and memorable way to think about the difference between primitive recursive and recursive functions.

> *Primitive recursive* functions are those that can be computed (from the trivial initial functions) by using *for* loops as the basic programming structure.

There are *bounded* loops [we know as we enter how many cycles to execute]. We can, though, nest them one inside the other, and chain together such nested loops. 'For loops' correspond to definitions by primitive recursion.

> *Recursive* ($\mu$-recursive) functions are those that can be computed (from the trivial initial functions) by using *for loops* and/or *do until* loops.

'Do until' loops involve *unbounded* searches until some condition is satisfied [as we enter the loop, we don't know how many times we will need to cycle around], so correspond to definitions by minimization.

So perhaps what needs to be 'diagrammed', if anything, is the difference between bounded and unbounded loopings.

[For more about this way of thinking about the difference between primitive recursive and $\mu$-recursive functions, see my *Introduction to Gödel's Theorems*, the first edition of which should be in most uni libraries.]

Comment: Thanks for your excellent description of the difference between how primitive recursive and recursive functions behave. I can now see that the difference lies in the nature of the loops. Depicting this will be an interesting project- I'll have to post it on here, as and when I come up with something! Your book looks really interesting- I shall have to track it down.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to visualize in an algebraic manner the recursive operator of the Primitive Recursive Function class: the Natural Numbers Object (NNO) in the context of a cartesian (or even monoidal) category. It allows to define Primitive Recursion by showing the relations diagramatically. You can see an extensive definition and characterizations in ncatlab.org/nlab/show/natural+numbers+object

On the other hand, in [this paper](https://academic.oup.com/logcom/article-abstract/21/2/253/941365) you can find a whole description of the class in terms of trees where the vertices are functions labelled by the usual operators.

The latter description makes use of the NNO diagram (and others).